# How to insert a column in BigTable using Hbase Client Put operation with past creation date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to execute an HBase client Put operation with a calculated timestamp equivalent of the year "Thu Sep 21 12:50:34 EDT 1950" which is a negative value.

**Use Case:** Setting a past creation date to execute an expected TTL on values

**Reference:** [How to set a future insert date in Google Cloud Bigtable? Trying to calculate it using TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629511/how-to-set-a-future-insert-date-in-google-cloud-bigtable-trying-to-calculate-it/52637832#52637832)

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp cannot be negative. ts=-608368165717
```

**Code:**

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long colFam_TTL = cfDescriptor1.getTimeToLive() * 1000; // TTL: Forever => 2147483647 Seconds
long expiry_past = now - colFam_TTL;
long creationTime = (expiry_past + 3600000); // Expected TTL : 1 hour(3600000 ms)
Put p = new Put(rowkey, creationTime);
```

The calculation works fine for column families with TTL set as maxage:1h or maxage:5d

Is there a workaround for this? How can I set a similar ts?

Comment: Your problem is just the negative start date. So to overcome this problem you can just shift all your dates. For example add 50 years to all your dates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but as noted by another commenter, the issue is that the timestamps Cloud Bigtable timestamps must be non-negative.

In this case, the problem is that as you noted, as written your creationTime has a negative value and the timestamp value must be a positive value, interpreted as milliseconds from the Unix epoch for any of the time-based GC expressions.

It seems like what you really want is to compute colFam_TTL - now, rather than the opposite, and clamp it at 0.